# Addwithvalue causing syntax error

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I have a stored procedure `spSchedulerCheck` that executes fine from SQL Server.  It takes a single parameter, `@jn`.  Trying to run this from VB/ASP.Net throws me a syntax error (which I'm catching).

VB Code:

```
Public Function ScheduleCheck()
    Dim sText As String
    Using cn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ProductionDatabaseConnectionString1").ConnectionString)
        cn.Open()
        Dim cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SchedulerCheck", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jn", Trim(Request.QueryString("jn").ToString()))
        Try
            Using reader As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                If reader.Read() Then
                    sText = reader(0).ToString()
                End If
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ex.Message
        End Try

        If Not cn Is Nothing Then
            cn.Close()
        End If
    End Using
        Return sText
End Function
```

SP:

```
USE [Production Database 2]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SchedulerCheck]    Script Date: 12/11/2013 15:31:48 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SchedulerCheck] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @jn as nvarchar(max)

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
declare @pn nvarchar(10);
set @pn = (select Proposalnumber from tblprj_management where jobnumber = @jn);

select ReturnCode = case
    when not exists (select * from tblprj_equipmentscope where jobnumber = @jn)
        then 'Could not find scope'
    when not exists (select * from tblprj_frcriteria where jobnumber = @jn and 'FR' in (select equipment from tblprj_equipmentscope where jobnumber = @jn)) 
        then 'Could not find FR Criteria entry'
    when not exists (select * from tblprj_wccriteria where jobnumber = @jn and 'WC' in (select equipment from tblprj_equipmentscope where jobnumber = @jn)) 
        then 'Could not find WC Criteria entry'
    when not exists (select * from tblprj_sctcriteria where jobnumber = @jn and 'SCT' in (select equipment from tblprj_equipmentscope where jobnumber = @jn)) 
        then 'Could not find SCT Criteria entry'
    when not exists (select * from tblprj_accriteria where jobnumber = @jn and 'AC' in (select equipment from tblprj_equipmentscope where jobnumber = @jn)) 
        then 'Could not find AC Criteria entry'
    when not exists (select * from tblprj_LFcriteria where jobnumber = @jn and 'LF' in (select equipment from tblprj_equipmentscope where jobnumber = @jn)) 
        then 'Could not find LF Criteria entry'
    when not exists (select * from tblprj_laborest where proposalnumber = @pn)
        and not exists (select * from tblprj_mfglaborest assy where proposalnumber = @pn)
        then 'Could not find labor estimates'
    else 'Success'
    end


END

GO
```

Seems to me like this should return one of the messages in the SP, not error out.  In fact, running it from the SQL server indeed runs as expected.  Some troubleshooting also shows that it runs as expected when I don't provide a Parameter, and only freaks out when I try to pass one.  What am I doing that's causing the error?

EDIT: Error is `Syntax Error near SchedulerCheck`

Comment: Added in Edit at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a stored procedure you need to change the property [CommandType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from its default of `Text` to `StoredProcedure`

```
  Dim cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SchedulerCheck", cn)
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
```

Otherwise the CommandText `SchedulerCheck` is interpreted as a normal sql text 
(like it was a `SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE`). Of course this result in a Syntax Error.

The AddWithValue has nothing to do with the error message

Comment: Commenting it out caused it to run normally, without the error message.  Threw me off.  Thanks!  EDIT: only if it's given a default value for the parameter, it would seem.  My mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `CommandType` of you command to be `StoredProcedure`. The default is `Text`.

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
```